# counting frequencies in dataframe by group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataframe

```
name = rep(c('Vasia','Petia'),10)
something = c("a","b","c",'d','e','f',"a","b","c",'d','e','f',"a","b","c",'d','e','f','a','b','c')
tablica = cbind(name,something)
```

I need to get frequencies by names.I tired to use `table` function:

```
    table(tablica)
tablica
    a     b     c     d     e     f Petia Vasia 
    4     4     4     3     3     3    10    11
```

But  need another result:

```
            a     b     c     d     e     f
 Petia      0     4     0     4     0     3
 Vasia      4     0     4     0     3     0
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: You are creating a matrix with `cbind`, do `tablica = data.frame(name,something)` and then use `table(tablica)`

Comment: Try `table(tablica$name,tablica$something)`

Comment: Alternatively, `xtabs(~ name + something, data = tablica)`. It is numerically equivalent, but adds dim-names (a convenience), and its formula interface allows for (imho) more readable code and easier (code-golf) addition of variables.